# Is $\sqrt{\left(\operatorname{Si}(x)-\frac\pi2\right)^2+\operatorname{Ci}(x)^2}$ completely monotone?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, definite-integrals, special-functions

Recall the definitions of the [sine](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) and [cosine integrals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html):
$$\operatorname{Si}(x)=\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}t dt,\quad\operatorname{Ci}(x)=-\int_x^\infty\frac{\cos t}t dt.$$
Both functions are oscillating, with a countably infinite number of minima and maxima.

Note that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\operatorname{Si}(x)=\frac\pi2,\quad\lim_{x\to\infty}\operatorname{Ci}(x)=0.$$
Consider the following function:
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\left(\operatorname{Si}(x)-\frac\pi2\right)^2+\operatorname{Ci}(x)^2}.$$
[image: Function graph]
It appears that the function $f(x)$ and all its derivatives are monotonic  for $x>0$. Specifically, the function itself and all its derivatives of an even order are strictly decreasing, and all its derivative of an odd order are strictly increasing.

Is it actually true? If so, then how can we prove it?

Comment: Hint. $f$ can be written as $$ f(x) = \left| \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-xs}}{s-i}\,\mathrm{d}s \right|, $$ which can be easily verified to be monotone decreasing. I am not sure at this point why $f$ need to be [*completely monotone*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions), though.

Comment: There are other pairs of oscillating functions that appear to have the same property: Bessel $J_\nu(x), Y_\nu(x)$, Fresnel integrals $S(x), C(x)$, etc. It looks that in each case such a pair can be converted into another pair of functions: an amplitude and a phase, both of which are completely monotone.

Comment: It seems that $f(x)^{\alpha}$ is completely monotone for any $\alpha > 0$. In other words, $f$ is infinitely divisible. I was unable to prove this claim neither. Also the following representation may be slightly helpful but I am not sure at this point: $$ f(x)^2 = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-xt} \frac{\log(1+t^2)}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t. $$

Comment: Nothing constructive here, just a point of curiosity - why is $\operatorname{Ci}$ defined using the negative out front?

Comment: @K.defaoite probably so the derivative is the integrand. You can't define it as $\int_{-\infty}^x \cos(t)/t\,dt$ because of the pole at zero.